# SharePoint environment to practice

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, environment, trial-version

I am about to quit my current job. This means that I won´t be able to use their SharePoint environment anymore.

Is there a way to get a SharePoint 2013 environment to practice?

Comment: what roles you are administration or development? is sharepoint online or on prem?

Comment: I would prefer on Premises

Comment: Is there anywhere i could practice using sharepoint from the administrative perspective

Answer (score 13):

There are a lot of opportunities. The cheapest one would be to sign up for Office 365, where you have SharePoint Online for a few bucks a month. Or if you want to run the server version, you'd need an Azure account to use your SharePoint Server in the cloud. See [Get started with Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/get-started/).

Or one year free by participating in the developer program of Office 365. See 
[Join the Microsoft Office 365 Developer Program](https://dev.office.com/devprogram).

Comment: He can use O365 trial too for sometime before subscribing it. so that will save his penny.

Comment: @JohnZachariah Or one year for free in the Dev program :)

Answer (score 8):

You can create an environment on a virtual machine an install SharePoint **trial for 180 days**.

> When prompted, provide a product key. You can use one of the following
>   trial product keys. The trial period is 180 days. You can convert to a
>   licensed installation at any time during the trial or after the trial
>   has expired by entering the appropriate product key in Central
>   Administration.
>
> - Enterprise trial product key: NQGJR-63HC8-XCRQH-MYVCH-3J3QR
> - Standard trial product key: RTNGH-MQRV6-M3BWQ-DB748-VH7DM

Source: [SharePoint Server 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51493)

Comment: Though this is suggested I am not sure, how easy for people to setup virtual environment and tried with SP On-Premises, at least for me I haven't tried that. if you have any step by step explanation that would help me as well as him too.

Answer (score 6):

If you like to access Server Object Model you can go with the @jpussacq approach of using trail account.

The other option is, as of now Microsoft is giving one year free SPO developer tenant account under dev program. You can follow [this](https://dev.office.com/devprogram) url to know more.

Comment: Excellently put, this would help like-minded people too. Thanks for spreading awareness on this.

Comment: Just to inform you, I had registered my developer tenant around 8 months ago. The developer tenant are different from production tenant. You'll get all the updates on these developer tenant first. It is good most of the time, but some time due to bug in build you may stuck for a while till MS resolve the issue. I faced one such issue and it took almost two weeks to resolve. So be prepared for that as well.

Comment: thats like beta version ,so we are developers who set to the brace for impact. good added word of caution.

Comment: yes exactly like beta version.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to get the free subscription apart from Benny's suggestion.

If you own a MSDN subscription then you will get following benefits.

- Office 365 Developer Subscription: Develop, test, and deploy add-ins
  for Office and SharePoint. Includes a one-tenant SharePoint Online
  Developer Site.
- Azure $150 monthly credit. You can build you own sharepoint farm.
- Pluralsight Full annual subscription. Learn SharePoint.

As JPUSSACQ recommend, you can spin up a virtual machine on your laptop or pc and install the SharePoint trial version or SharePoint foundation ( as you asked for 2013).

https://nikpatel.net/2013/09/08/prepping-up-windows-8-hyper-v-for-sharepoint-lab-vms/

https://www.petri.com/setup-sharepoint-2013-development-environment-installation

Comment: Need the enterprise MSDN subscription (not MSDN professional) in order to get a developer tenant: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/pricing/