# Free Office 365 subscription

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am looking for a free subscription for SharePoint / Project online / office 365,

My question : What're the steps to can access SharePoint / Project online / office 365 for free?

Thanks
Andy

Comment: check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218311/sharepoint-environment-to-practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to get the free subscription apart from Benny's suggestion.

If you or your company own a MSDN subscription then you will get following benefits.

- **Office 365 Developer Subscription:** Develop, test, and deploy add-ins for Office and SharePoint. **Includes a one-tenant SharePoint Online Developer Site**.
- Azure $150 monthly credit. You can build you own sharepoint farm.
- **Pluralsight** Full annual subscription. Learn SharePoint.

Comment: yes waqas  our company own a a MSDN subscription , but we don't know the registration step ?

Comment: ask you company, asssing a license to you then go here and register urself. https://my.visualstudio.com

Comment: Ask you company, asssing a license to you How ?

Comment: Basically, companies own Volume Licensing and they have multiple license for MSDN as per their agreement (vary for everyone). They have to assign a MSDN license to your windows live ID, once they do. then go to the url and register yourself

Comment: windows live ID = outlook account or my company email

Comment: i think both works, i assigned it to my outlook. But i am sure it will work with company email but we have to register that email as live id 1st

Answer (score 7):

[Join the Microsoft Office 365 Developer Program](https://dev.office.com/devprogram) which will get you this:

> Get virtual and in-person learning opportunities, benefits to help you
>   become more innovative and successful, and access to connect with
>   other developers.
>
> - One-year, FREE Office 365 developer subscription
> - Access to online trainings
> - In-person office hours with Microsoft engineers
> - Chances to win tickets to Microsoft conferences and industry events
> - Opportunities to participate in virtual hackathons to build modern productivity solutions with Office
> - Opportunities to meet with other developers in your area
> - Previews of and insights into Office Extensibility
> - Announcements